# datagridview new row indexes

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
|Column 1|Column 2|
|1       |1       |
|2       |2       |
|3       |3       |
|4       |4       |
|5       |5       |
|6       |6       |
|7       |7       |
|8       |8       |
|9       |9       |
|        |        |
```

Let's say i am displaying this at my datagridview, and now i am adding new row (row 10). I am checking if user left any column empty before i use that data later, and now if user inserted something in column 1, and left column 2 empty i check it and display him message "column 2 can't be empty", but after that i want his selection (currentrow) to be at that empty cell and my problem is that new row does not have index (it has, but when i use it, i got error that i can't use index that is greater than max rows). How can i solve it.

Here is code part where i am checking that

```
            int nRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            int currColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int currRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            string id = dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string opis = dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Polje broj ne moze biti prazno!");
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, nRows];
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(opis))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Polje opis ne moze biti prazno!");
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, nRows];
            }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you would post the code that you describe. That makes it easier to help you

Comment: I added the code in post

Answer (score 0):

One option could be subscribing to [`RowsAdded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView.RowsAdded += dataGridView1_RowsAdded


private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender,
     DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    // validation code.
    e.RowIndex; // newly added row index.
}
```

Comment: I can get index with rows.count at cellValueChanged, but when i try to use it in currentCell, it says 
 
    Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: `rows.Count` returns a count, but what you need is newlyadded row. Am I  getting it wrong here?

Comment: Hmm i didn't pay attention, but now when i get index with rowindex, i get the same but that is not problem. Problem is if i get index 10, i set currentCell to [1, 10] (that is for column 2) but for some reason it set it to 1, 9 (last row but not newly one)

Comment: Index what youget is `RowIndex` so you should access the elements by using `dataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value` and `dataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].Value` (for second cell).

Comment: I do not get you but i tried something else and figured this out:

I set
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
And when it need to set current cell to column2, first row it doesn't, it set it on the last column, last row (not new one). So now i am totaly confused